# Selenium WebDriver: Scroll custom scrollbar till it will reach up to desired element

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I am trying to automate WhatsApp web application. The contacts div has a custom scrollbar. The group I have to post a message is not displayed on the web page and hence cannot be clicked. How can I scroll upto that perticular group? I have tried following code but it is not working.

```
 @Test
 void begin(){
    openBrowser();
    driver.get("https://web.whatsapp.com/");
    sleep(10000);
    WebElement scroll = driver.findElement(By.id("pane-side")); // locator of contacts div.
    ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", scroll);
    //Thread.sleep(500); 
    //WebElement groupName = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[text()='Word of the day']")); //locator of group
        }
```

[image]

Comment: Have you tried with Action class?

Answer (score 0):

A helper class for custom scroll bar:

```
public class ScrollHelper {

    private static String VeticalScrollScript = "arguments[0].scrollTop = arguments[1]";
    private static String HorizonScrollScript = "arguments[0].scrollLeft = arguments[1]";
    private JavascriptExecutor jsExecutor;

    public ScrollHelper() {
        this.jsExecutor = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
    }

    public ScrollHelper asHorizon(scrollTarget, scrollContext) {
        if(isPresentHorizonScrollBar(scrollContext)) {
            int offset = scrollTarget.getLocation().getX() - 
                         scrollContext.getLocation().getX();
            this.jsExecutor.executeScript(HorizonScrollScript, scrollContext, offset);
        }
        return this;
    }

    public ScrollHelper asVertical(scrollTarget, scrollContext) {
        if(this.isPresentVerticalScrollBar(scrollContext)) {
            int offset = scrollTarget.getLocation().getY() - 
                         scrollContext.getLocation().getY();
            this.jsExecutor.executeScript(VeticalScrollScript, scrollContext, offset);
        }
        return this;
    }

    private boolean isPresentHorizonScrollBar(WebElement scrollContext) {
        String script = "return arguments[0].scrollWidth > arguments[0].clientWidth;";
        return (Boolean) (this.jsExecutor.executeScript(script, scrollContext));
    }

    private boolean isPresentVerticalScrollBar(WebElement scrollContext) {
        String script = "return arguments[0].scrollHeight > arguments[0].clientHeight;";
        return (Boolean) (this.jsExecutor.executeScript(script, scrollContext));
    }
}
```

For your case:

```
ScrollHelper scroll = new ScrollHelper(driver);

scroll.asVertical(
    scrollTarget, // the group
    scrollContext // the element who owns the custom scroll bar
);
```

In below case, the `scrollContext` is the `pre` highlighted by Green line, 
Not its parent `<div class="post-text">` or other element. You need to find out the correct element who owns the custom scroll bar as value for `scrollContext`.

A way to find the correct `scrollContext` is to see element has CSS style `over-flow`, if you uncheck the checkbox before `over-flow`, you will notice the scroll bar will disappear,  and come back when check it.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this? (Tweak for your project!)

```
while (true) {
            try {
                WebElement backgroundDivInsideScrollingPane = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='idOfAnElementInTheScrollingPane']"));
                backgroundDivInsideScrollingPane.sendKeys(Keys.PAGE_DOWN);

                WebElement elementToBeFound = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//myElementLocatorHere"));
                break;
            } catch (Exception ignored) {
                // Exception because element can't be found yet - Ignore!
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

[image]
[image]
Whatsapp Messaging section with this code
You will be able to take the Page Down and the Page Up.
Note:
100% working :)

Message Detail Scroll Down and Scroll Up

```
        private void SyhMhzScrollDetailPageUP()
    {
        IWebElement scroll = drv.FindElementByXPath("//div[@class='_1ays2']");
        scroll.SendKeys(Keys.PageUp);
    }
    private void SyhMhzScrollDeatilPageDown()
    {
        IWebElement scroll = drv.FindElementByXPath("//div[@class='_1ays2']");
        scroll.SendKeys(Keys.PageDown);
    }
```

Message List Scroll Down and Scroll Up

```
        private void SyhMhfzMesgListScrollPageUP()
    {
        IWebElement scroll = drv.FindElementByXPath("//div[@data-tab='4']");
        scroll.SendKeys(Keys.Up);
    }
    private void SyhmhfzMesgListPageDown()
    {
        IWebElement scroll = drv.FindElementByXPath("//div[@data-tab='4']");
        scroll.SendKeys(Keys.Down);
    }
```

You can also use the Nuget package here.
https://www.nuget.org/packages/Bekra.Whatshapp_Scroll_Down_Up/1.0.0